# Returning the index of the first integer in a list that is less than its index

Tags: python

I'm a beginner in python and I'm not sure how to do this.
Anyone know how I can fix my code please?

```
def smaller_index(items: list[int]) -> int:
    """
    Return the index of the first integer in items that is less than its index,
    or -1 if no such integer exists in items.
    
    >>> smaller_index([2, 5, 7, 99, 6])
    -1
    >>> smaller_index([-5, 8, 9, 16])
    0
    >>> smaller_index([5, 8, 9, 0, 1, 3])
    3
    """
    min_value = min(items)
    if items.count(min_value) > 1:
            return [i for i, x in enumerate(items) if x == min(items)]
    else:
           return items.index(min(items))
```

Comment: Iterate through the list. For each item, check if it's less than its index. If it is, return that item's index.

Comment: `next(v for i, v in enumerate(vs) if v < i)`

Comment: Actually, you're not far off to start with `enumerate(items)` - just need to compare idx, num...

Comment: The title of your post and the logic in your posted code do not match.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
def smaller_index(items: list) -> int:
    for i, n in enumerate(items):
        if n < i:
            return i
    return -1
```

Assuming I understand what you're trying to do, this can be as simple as you want it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for this problem.

```
def smaller_index(items: list) -> int:
    """
    Return the index of the first integer in items that is less than its index,
    or -1 if no such integer exists in items.

    #>>> smaller_index([2, 5, 7, 99, 6])
    -1
    #>>> smaller_index([-5, 8, 9, 16])
    0
    #>>> smaller_index([5, 8, 9, 0, 1, 3])
    3
    """
    for i in range(len(items)):
        if items[i] < i:
            return i
    return -1

print(smaller_index([5, 8, 9, 0, 1, 3]))
```

Breakdown of the logic:

- I changed the data-type indicated for items from list[int] to list - for some reason this indicated an error (need to investigate further)
- Iterate through the list using the indexes of their elements - compare them and if your condition is satisfied, return the value of the index.
- If no element in the element satisfies your condition, after the for loop is completed, return -1